# Deserializing the JSON Objest results in all null fields C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

My jsonResponse is something like this:

```
{"status":200,"data":{"first_name":"\u062e\u0633","last_name":"\u0635\u062f\u0627","national_code":"1","image_photo":"1.jpg","cellphone":"1234","city":{"id":1,"name":"x","created_at":"2017-02-27 17:54:44","updated_at":"2017-02-27 17:54:44"},"email":"something@gmail.com","even_odd":1,"Register Time":"2018-01-25 10:39:17","is_blocked":false,"receive_regular_offer":"false","level":1,"ride_count":0,"service_type":1,"bank":"\u0645","iban":"xy","card_number":"","holder":"\u062e\u0633","plate_number":"123","vehicle_model":"\u067e\u0698","vehicle_color":"\u062a\u0627\u06a9\u0633","unique_id":592875}}
```

I have created a class like this:

```
public class Driver
    {
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string national_code { get; set; }
        public string image_photo { get; set; }
        public string cellphone { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string even_odd { get; set; }
        public bool is_blocked { get; set; }
        public bool receive_regular_offer { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string ride_count { get; set; }
        public string service_type { get; set; }
        public string bank { get; set; }
        public string iban { get; set; }
        public string card_number { get; set; }
        public string holder { get; set; }
        public string vehicle_model { get; set; }
        public string vehicle_color { get; set; }
        public string unique_id { get; set; }
    }
```

and used this:

```
jsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Driver snappDriver = js.Deserialize<Driver>(jsonResponse);
```

But the result is all null!

Answer (score 1):

1.your class should be defined right

example:

```
void Main()
{
    var json =api();

    //dynamic
    var dynamic_json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json).Dump() as JObject;

    //strong type
    var strong_Type_json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Driver>(json).Dump() ;

}

string api(){
    return @"
{""status"":200,""data"":{""first_name"":""\u062e\u0633"",""last_name"":""\u0635\u062f\u0627"",""national_code"":""1"",""image_photo"":""1.jpg"",""cellphone"":""1234"",""city"":{""id"":1,""name"":""x"",""created_at"":""2017-02-27 17:54:44"",""updated_at"":""2017-02-27 17:54:44""},""email"":""something@gmail.com"",""even_odd"":1,""Register_Time"":""2018-01-25 10:39:17"",""is_blocked"":false,""receive_regular_offer"":""false"",""level"":1,""ride_count"":0,""service_type"":1,""bank"":""\u0645"",""iban"":""xy"",""card_number"":"""",""holder"":""\u062e\u0633"",""plate_number"":""123"",""vehicle_model"":""\u067e\u0698"",""vehicle_color"":""\u062a\u0627\u06a9\u0633"",""unique_id"":592875}}
    ";
}


public class City
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string national_code { get; set; }
    public string image_photo { get; set; }
    public string cellphone { get; set; }
    public City city { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public int even_odd { get; set; }
    public string Register_Time { get; set; }
    public bool is_blocked { get; set; }
    public string receive_regular_offer { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
    public int ride_count { get; set; }
    public int service_type { get; set; }
    public string bank { get; set; }
    public string iban { get; set; }
    public string card_number { get; set; }
    public string holder { get; set; }
    public string plate_number { get; set; }
    public string vehicle_model { get; set; }
    public string vehicle_color { get; set; }
    public int unique_id { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public int status { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

2.json's key `Register Time` in strong type is invalid name
[image]

[image]

you can add `_` in your json string to solve the problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to create exactly the same class definition as your json has. Your `Driver` class describes json object's `data` property.

```
public class DriverWrapper
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Driver data { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create another object class that handles **status** and **data** property

try this

Create a class **Response**

```
class Response{

  public int status { get; set;}
  public Driver data { get; set;}

}
```

and do it this way

```
jsonResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Response snappDriver = js.Deserialize<Response>(jsonResponse);
```